# how to detect the sound peak power through iphone application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

all

I can't solve my problem, I want when the app start it will detect the sound if the recording sound peak Power is greater the 0.9 then it will record that sound , and if its peak level is lower than 0.9 then it will stop.

how can I compute the peak level of the recording sound.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Apple has a demo called SpeakHere.  Inside, you will find an example how to read the 'level meters' from their audio frameworks.

or this snippet

```
[soundRecorder updateMeters];
//NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f", [soundRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
decibelLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Decibel %f db", [soundRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0]];
```

Edit #2

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

The above link gives a clear understanding what -160 means.  It is the minimum while 0 is the maximum.

In your case, you are looking for (either average power or peak power, up to you) anything greater than 0.9 then you can proceed with the following two options:

1) see if (output+160)> (0.9*160)) // maybe you would want to tune 0.9 to other values

or
2) see if (output +160) > 144 // hardcoding it

or
3) see if (output > -16) // hardcoding it

Comment: @Gray Tsui, I can't understand that what is giong-on on this AQMeter .. b/c in recording I want to see the level of the meter. I want that when the user say anything it will automatically record it, and after when the user stop saying any thing it will  stop.it..              I want simply meter reading.. of the sound

Comment: i assume you are using AVSoundRecorder, too. 
 [soundRecorder updateMeters];
 //NSLog(@"Average input: %f Peak input: %f", [soundRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0], [soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
 decibelLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Decibel %f db", [soundRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0]];

Comment: please see the edited answer.  decibelLabel is the Label and soundRecorder is init from AVAudioRecorder.

Comment: @Gary Tsui it only print "Average input: -160.000000 Peak input: -160.00000" this vlaues, i run the code 2 or 3 times but the output is same

Comment: Did it record though ?  i got this from own code snippet, i just tested and confirmed.  The peakpower varies accordingly.

Comment: @Gary if you have any sample code, then plz give me the link. of that code.. the peak power can't change after -160 or -120

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

This gives a clear understanding of what you should do with the numbers.  160 is the minimum and it also indicates 0 should be the maximum.  in your case, the easiest would (output+160) / 160 , if it is > 0.9, you get your results.  or a better way, 0.9 of the range [-160,0], you just hv to compare if output > -16.

Comment: @Gary thnx for help me in this issue, I solve Alhumdullah 75% of this work